# Simple connected eulerian graph $G = (V, E)$ cannot be bipartite if $(V, E - \{e_1,e_2,e_3\})$ is also eulerian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, eulerian-path

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple connected eulerian graph, I was asked to prove that it cannot be bipartite if $(V, E - \{ e_1,e_2,e_3 \})$ is also eulerian.

While processing my proof I came up with this simple, connected and eulerian graph: $$v_1-v_2-v_3-v_4-v_5-v_6-v_1$$
$G$ is also **bipartite** e.g. let $A = \{v_1,v_3,v_5\}$,$B = \{v_2,v_4,v_6\}$. If I would remove the edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4$, $$v_4-v_5-v_6-v_1, v_2, v_3$$ is still eulerian, what am I missing?

Edit: I now noticed that an eulerian graph is defined as a graph that conatins an eulerian **cycle** my example only has an **eulerian path** therefore the graph is not eulerian.

Comment: The edit is correct, assuming that you’re talking about the graph that remains after you’ve removed the three edges. Did you also have a question about the proof?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have came up with my own proof eventually but I would like to see another proof to compare it to mine and perhaps learn from it

Comment: The proof that occurs to me is simply to note that every vertex of $G$ must have even degree, and all edges must be between the two parts, so removing three edges changes the total degree of each side by $3$ and must therefore produce at least one odd vertex in each part.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Im not sure if that is a full proof? can you elaborate? My proof shows that since every vertex of $G$ and $H$ (the new sub-graph) must have an even degree, $G$ must have a cycle of length 3 inside of it for  $H$ to be eulerian therefore $G$ is not bipratite

Comment: It’s complete: the sum of the degrees in each part of $G$ is even, and there is no edge between vertices in the same part, so removing $3$ edges reduces the sum of the degrees in each part by $3$. The new sums are therefore odd, which is possible only if some vertex has odd degree. It’s really not substantially different from your approach, which amounts to observing that the only way to avoid getting an odd vertex is to remove a triangle of edges, which doesn’t exist in a bipartite graph.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Cool, thanks. If you wish you could post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Done! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is Eulerian, each vertex has even degree, and the sum of the degrees in each of its two parts is even. Since $G$ is bipartite, all of the edges are between the two parts, so removing $3$ of them reduces the sum of the degrees of the vertices in each part by $3$, leaving an odd total. This is possible only if at least one vertex in each part now has odd degree, in which case the new graph cannot be Eulerian. (In fact the only way to remove $3$ edges from an Eulerian graph and **not** produce a vertex of odd degree is to remove a triangle of edges, which does not exist in a bipartite graph.)